# How to skip certain part strings if the coefficient is zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-3.10

In this question, we want to return the function like this result but I do not want things like 0^5 to occur(because 0^5 is equal to 0 and I do not want to show that, how can I write a code to let the system detect that the several parts are 0? And when I want to use the degree function in `Class Poly`, i want the inserted poly number to be the highest coefficient, how can I do that? we can place the insert function later, that is my code:

```py
Class Poly():
    def __init__(self,coe=[]):
        self.coefficient=coe
    def degree(self,poly=int()):
        self.highestpoly=poly
    def insert(self,polynomial,coefficient):
        self.polynomial=polynomial
        self.coefficient=coefficient #solve that later
    def __str__(self):
        e=self.coefficient[5]
        c=self.coefficient[4]
        a=self.coefficient[3]
        b=self.coefficient[2]
        z=self.coefficient[1]
        d=self.coefficient[0]
        epart=str(e)+str("^")+str(5)+'+'
        cpart=str(c)+str("^")+str(4)+'+'
        apart=str(a)+str("^")+str(3)+'+'
        bpart=str(b)+str("^")+str(2)+'+'
        zpart=str(c)+str("^")+str(1)+'+'
        dpart=str(d)
        return epart+cpart+apart+bpart+zpart+dpart


print(Poly([0,0,3,2,1,0]))
>>> tommy1111@infra04-wg013 lab11 % python3 -i mycode.py 0^5+1^4+2^3+3^2+1^1+0 (result)
```

Comment: if my coefficent is 1 or -1, I do not want to 1 or -1 to occur,

Comment: A couple of things: please try to look upon string formatting

Comment: I want to keep it as "4x^3" and out put as a string but when it turn"0x^3" i do not want it occur in my code,i am confused on string formatting!! How can i do both math and edit string!

Comment: That is what I told you to research about, in short, it's called `fstrings` such as in `C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I think you want, the order of the coefficients is wrong but That wasn't the main issue.

```
class Poly():
    def __init__(self, coe=None):
        if coe is None:
            coe = []
        self.coefficient = coe

    def degree(self, poly=int()):
        self.highestpoly = poly

    def insert(self, polynomial, coefficient):
        self.polynomial = polynomial
        self.coefficient = coefficient  # solve that later

    def __str__(self):
        p = []
        for i, c in enumerate(self.coefficient):
            if c != 0:
                p.append(f"{c}x^{i}")

        return " + ".join(p)

print(Poly([0,0,3,2,1,0]))
```

output:

```
3x^2 + 2x^3 + 1x^4
```

Comment: thank u, very good! i will solve the rest by myself